# How to copy variables to a different running process?

Tags: android, service, process

First off, I hope I am asking the right question (otherwise I'll delete it).

I'll describe what's happening and what I think is the reason:

I have an app with a `Service` running in background in a different process than my `UI`. Both `UI` and `Service` need the same information from my server, so they share this info. I'm sending this info from my `UI` to the `Service` when it is started, so I copy it to my `Service` and it should therefore be independent from my `UI`.

Problem is: if I close my `UI` (kill my app, whereas `Service` is still running) I get a crash on my `Service` because the variables I copied from my `UI` are null.

I first copied it in my `Service` when I received info from my `UI` using:

```
Service.str = strFromUi;
```

But as it would have the same reference, I tried to do:

```
Service.str = new String(strFromUi);
```

And I checked that they do not have the same reference (`str == strFromUi -> false`).

I don't have a clear idea on what's happening. Maybe `new String(strFromUI)` is creating a variable in my `UI` process, and when I kill this process my `Service` can no longer access it.

Any help or references is very appreciated!

Comment: Your two lines of code are the same thing. There is no (simple) pass by reference in Java. Where are you calling those lines of code? In Service or UI? Also, have you tried [Services and Handlers](http://blog.denevell.org/android-service-handler-tutorial.html)?

Comment: Sorry, but they are not. If I compare these two variables, in the first line they are true, and in the second line they are false (it creates another instance of the very same String, which AndroidStudio even tells me is redundant). My intention was to maybe create another instance in the Service process. That is being called in the Service when I receive the info from the UI. And thanks, but this reference was not helpful in my case, already got my Service running ok besides this info I need :(

Comment: "Service running in background in a different process" why? why do you need this?

Comment: Honestly this was not my choice, but a former developer's who started this project. From what I read it makes not a big difference, and I changed it from/to another process with no apparent difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not what I imagined. When I kill my app (UI) my Service gets recreated for some (still unknown) reason to me.

My solution was to persist this variable in Preferences, so when my Service is recreated it reads from Preferences and it is able to keep running normally.

Comment: This problem was different from what I questioned. Shall I delete it? (meta question)